# How to show frequency of different time with curve graph

Tags: r

My data：
https://app.box.com/s/dmmlhl37qn7ua5thbh2m5fmfakz3ctsw
The dataset is like:

```
> head(data)
  timestamp Type
1  10:56:00    a
2  10:56:00    a
3  08:30:00    a
4  06:56:00    a
5  17:11:00    a
6  16:55:00    a
```

I want a curve graph to show the frequency over the whole 24hours.And different line for different `Type:a,b,c`,like：

[image]

I did it with a histogram like below:

[image]

but how to show different Types with curve graph?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You have several options. One is by adding `color = Type` or `fill = Type` to `aes()`. Or, you could add `facet_wrap(~ Type)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- read.csv("test2.csv")

library(lubridate)

#Get ranges
tt <- unique(data$Type)
xlim <- c(Inf,-Inf)
ymax <- 0
for(i in 1:length(tt)) {
  t1 <- density(period_to_seconds(hms(data$timestamp[data$Type==tt[i]])))
  xlim[1] <- min(c(xlim[1],t1$x))
  xlim[2] <- max(c(xlim[2],t1$x))
  ymax <- max(c(ymax,t1$y))
}

plot(NA, type="n", xlim=xlim, ylim=(c(0,ymax)), xlab="Seconds", ylab="Density")

#Plot the densities
for(i in 1:length(tt)) {
  lines(density(period_to_seconds(hms(data$timestamp[data$Type==tt[i]]))), col=i)
}
legend("topleft", legend=tt, col=seq_along(tt), lty=1)
```